# array of pointers to objects in c++ using templates

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have two questions, first i'm trying to create a hash table: am i instantiating the array correctly? I am trying to make a dynamic array of pointers to linked lists for chaining: the linked list nodes store by value.  I think my ItemType** syntax is incorrect, though i'm not sure:  here's my understanding, and please correct me if i'm mistaken.

The first * instantiates 'HashArray' as an array, then the second * instantiates it as an array of pointers to the head of each linked list: I should be pointing to a node. Node is nested within LinkedList; though it is public. Anyway this sounds absurd but should it read something along the lines of "LinkedList::Node::ItemType** HashArray"?
any suggestions?

edit: I didn't include my copy/delete/assign constructors for simplicity:

edit 2: nor did i include my 'hash'/'grow function'/'shrink function'.  Obviously there's no point in writing a remove function etc until i have the insert written and the templates working beforehand... Let me know if it would be helpful to post more of what i have.  right now i'm getting compile errors

C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'list< type >' *' to 'std::string *'
on the lines

HashArray[index] = LinkedList;

That should help pin down the issue

```
template <typename ItemType>
class HashSet {


int oldCapacity;
int capacity;
int size;
ItemType** HashArray;

HashSet()   {
    HashArray = new ItemType*[capacity] ;
    memset(HashArray, 0, sizeof(ItemType*)*capacity);
    size=0;
    capacity = 0;
    oldCapacity = 0;
}

void insert(const ItemType& item){
    list <ItemType> *LinkedList= new list<ItemType>();
    unsigned int index = hash(item);

    if(HashArray[index]== NULL)
    {
    LinkedList->pushback(item);
    HashArray[index] = LinkedList;
    }
    else if(!LinkedList->find(item)) //if it's not in the list
    {
    LinkedList->pushback(item);
    HashArray[index] = LinkedList;
    }
    else //in list already
        return;

}
}
```

Comment: at first your class must have a semicolon in the end. I'm sure your problems are not because of this, but still it's an error. 
`class HashSet {
    ...
    ...
}  ; <-
  `

Comment: Do you have a good reason for not using a `std::hash_map` container, rather than reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Yeah- I guess this should have a homework tag- this is for a Project where I'm not allowed to use any std library containers..

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier not all of my code is posted for simplicity